# Finding word position in a string for java

Tags: java

I have looked around for another answer on here, but i didn't really understand how to convert it to my own code. 
I am trying to find where "COUNTRY" is found in a phrase so:

```
String word = "COUNTRY";
String sentence = "ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOU COUNTRY";
```

It should output that the word is in the 5th and 17th positions.

Many Thanks

EDIT: I realised that it also need to ignore the case. Sorry for not saying this sooner

Comment: What have you tried? HINT: split the string into an array of strings, one string for each word.

Comment: regex and matcher and group find should be part of your thinking.

Comment: regex and matcher and group would be like trying to teach calculus before addition and subtraction.

Comment: @NickJ I have tried using a loop and i did some things with case ignore - but it doesn't see to work well

Comment: @Darrkwolf "it doesn't seem to work well" - that's a little vague

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to check if a String contains a Word then you can use the `.contains("");` method provided by String

```
String word = "COUNTRY";
String sentence = "ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOU COUNTRY";
    
System.out.println(sentence.contains(word));
//will return true;
```

If you want to find all the words inside the sentence then use this:

```
String word = "COUNTRY";
String sentence = "ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOU COUNTRY";
    
if (sentence.contains(word)) {
    String[] sentenceWords = sentence.split(" ");

    for (String wordInSentence : sentenceWords) {
        if (wordInSentence.equals(word)) {
            System.out.println(wordInSentence);
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you want to know the exact location of a specific word, then try this:

```
String word = "COUNTRY";
String sentence = "ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOU COUNTRY";
    
if (sentence.contains(word)) {
    String[] sentenceWords = sentence.split(" ");
        
    for (int i = 0; i < sentenceWords.length; i++) {
        if (sentenceWords[i].equals(word)) {
            System.out.println(word + " is located as the: " + i + "th string");
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** See that i use `.equals();` on String objects see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) post for more information!

**EDIT:**

To ignore the case you can use `String.equalsIgnoreCase()` instead of `String.equals()`

Comment: Thanks for this- though is there a way to ignore the case on the your last awnser

Answer (score 1):

You can use this piece of code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String word = "COUNTRY";
    String sentence = "ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOU COUNTRY";
    String[] listWord = sentence.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < listWord.length; i++) {
        if (listWord[i].equals(word)) {
            System.out.println(i+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this- though is there a way to ignore the case on the your awnser

Comment: what did you mean by :  is there a way to ignore the case on the your awnser ?

Comment: I mean is there a way for if the word to find was just country then it would still work

Comment: you can add after the if a break();

Answer (score 0):

Better use this functions present in java.lang.*,ie in String class.It is non Static...

int indexOf(String str) 
           Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified substring. 
 int indexOf(String str, int fromIndex) 
           Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified substring, starting at the specified index.

```
String s1="Hello I love my country,i belong to my country",s2="country";
System.out.println( s1.indexOf(s2));
```